# NatTable Custom Spanning Data Provider, Cell will be only span if they are part of parent group

Tags: eclipse, nattable

I have used AutomaticSpanningDataProvider to spanning the columns, its perfectly spanning for repeated columns.

[image]

> 1. But i want to extend an AutomaticSpanningDataProvider to customize the
>      implementation to looks like in the above pic (Expected Custom
>      Spanning). In this case cell will be span if they are part of parent group.
> 2. One more observation I made, there is an thin lines in the spanned cells.
>      Is it would be possible to change the thin lines to no line and the thick line to thin line?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear to me where those thin lines are coming from. What painters are you using? Maybe it is because you are using the `BeveledBorderDecorator` in a non-header region. And IIRC the grid line rendering should be disabled in combination with the `BeveledBorderDecorator`.

And if you need a custom spanning behavior, well then implement it. The `AutomaticSpanningDataProvider` is just one default implementation that handles the same data to span automatically. You can implement your own `ISpanningDataProvider` with your custom logic and use that instead of the defaults. Actually that is the most common usage of spanning. Not sure what the question is.